# HTML5 Canvas Scale Calculation

Tags: html, canvas, scale

I'm working on a level editor for a game engine and I'd like to be able to zoom in/out.

So I tried the `ctx.scale(1.1, 1.1)` but I have no idea how to scale it out again. I have tried `ctx.scale(0.9, 0.9)` but I don't think it's correct.

I tried google as well as other questions here on stackoverflow to no help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out by experimentation :P

First, determine a factor to scale by. Such as `1.1`
If you scale in `1.1`, you need to scale it to `1/(1*1.1)` for zooming out again.